# Decay relativistic (in the Newton sense) velocity in particle system

Tags: math, game-physics, particle-system

I'm making a particle simulation where particles both attract and repel and have an ideal distance where the forces are balanced. I'd like to use it to simulate different types of matter.

The problem is that regardless of the forces between the atoms all the matter that I produce using this idea seems ends up having the consistency of very jittery jello. If I try to just decay the velocity of all particles (in an absolute sense), then it becomes less like jello, but if being propelled through space, slows down as if in some kind of thick gooey ether.

I'm thinking that if I had an algorithm where I am adjusting forces between particles, without using absolute velocity in any way (relative velocity between interacting particles is ok) I could cause the matter to "crystalize" without having it act as if its in a ether.

I have a vague understanding that atoms generate light when they vibrate with too much energy, which slows them down, I assume, and I'm hoping some sort of similar physics laws may help guide me to an algorithm to do this.

Specifically, it's a 2d system, written in Web GL, where I encode the particles in 2d graphics textures, so graphics card handles all the interactions. Each particle creates a field around it based on
the following equation:

f(x) = k/(l+(x-d)^2) * c

Where k, l, and d are universally constant, x is the distance from the particle. 
c is constant per particle type. One particle type could have a negative value, and another a positive, creating an attraction between the two. This is explained more below.

f(x) is multiplied to a normalized vector that is pointed away from the particle in question to get a force vector.

This equation creates a kind of force "donut" around the particle, based on the various values of k,l, and d.

(Right now I only have the above equation, but of course I could add others).

The field the particles live in contains the sum of all the fields generated by the particles. The change in velocity to the particle is determined as follows:

g(x) = c / m * f

where f is the total field vector at the particles location, m is the particles mass and c is the "field charge" of the particle type, also used in the above equation.

There are a variable number of fields. In the simplest scenario there is only 1 but in general I have 2, one for the electric force and another for a nuclear repelling force.

Comment: I don't think it is a right forum for that. It seems that you are trying to do a micro-level molecular simulation and expect it to come up with realistic macro-level behaviours - which is probably doable only in most hardcore supercomputer simulations. There might be some shortcuts/tricks to make it simplier - but you need to ask different crowd for that. Try http://physics.stackexchange.com/ (and please provide a lot more details in question regarding details of simulation).

Comment: Thanks, I added the question there, and added more detail.